# Merge multiple columns together based on a common column value in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge rows based on a common value i.e date of purchase.

[image: Dataframe]

[image: Output]

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = df.groupby(['DateOfPurchase'])['Item'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  DateOfPurchase        Item
0    19-Aug-2020  Apple,Eggs
1    20-Aug-2020      Banana
```